# How to make OpenLayers example work in jsFiddle

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, json

I'm working on a jsFiddle with a OpenLayers example in it. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/snapping.html

At the moment it's not working because it's not getting a response for the http request to get data. How do I fix that?

The jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TcuxA/6/ Go to the line "// create three vector layers" in the script. There are three requests for data. If you type the URLs in your browser you get the JSON, but my Firebug gives 3 errors when I run the jsFiddle.

I tried fixing with jsFiddle echo, but that didn't work. I don't know how to change the script to load the data otherwise.

Why can't I get the JSON by these URLs? What are good solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing to 'http://www.freetrack.nl/js/OpenLayers.js' for Openlayers but the example http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/snapping.html is
using 'http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/lib/OpenLayers.js'
which is different to your openlayers.js and missing all the libraries  [Single File Library] that are required.

replace:

```
http://www.freetrack.nl/js/OpenLayers.js
with
http://dev.openlayers.org/lib/OpenLayers.js
```

Comment: oh, oops, I fixed that in the next version and I gave the map some width and height. The problem is the jsons containing all the poly's, lines and points. How do I fix that. See: http://jsfiddle.net/TcuxA/7/

Comment: jsFiddle it won't get the data because the URL doesn't conform to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690123/parse-json-google-finance-in-jquery

Comment: Adding '&callback=?' to the URL didn't solve it. Since you can just view those jsons in your browser, I tried to put them into a var in the code and 'load' them that way in the Vector layer, but I'm not sure how to do that. http://jsfiddle.net/TcuxA/9/
I also tried the Script protocol to fix the same origin issue. But it gives some errors on the returned object. http://jsfiddle.net/TcuxA/10/